# Unexpected p-value distribution of Mann-Whitney U test under null hypothesis

Tags: python, inference, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, scipy

I am getting very unexpected results of p-value distribution of Mann-Whitney U test under null hypothesis.

I am working on a real data, but I was able to replicate the results on artificial data with similar distribution. Data distribution is similar to zero-inflated log-normal distribution.

The idea behind my analysis was to check whether I can use Mann-Whitney U test for my data. Initially, I performed similar test for regular T test, but due to non-normal distribution I am working on, I was getting too many type I errors. But for T test that is expected, as the test assumptions are not met. So I repeated the same simulation with Mann-Whitney U test, expecting that I will get uniform p-value distribution, but instead I got distribution very different from what I expected.

This is my code:

```
# loading libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
    
### Simulations
# Defining single simulation code
def process():
    # Sample first sample, it has 95% of zeros and rest is log-normal, using multiplication to merge both
    sample1 = (np.random.uniform(0, 1, 10_000_000)<0.05)*np.random.lognormal(mean=2.7, sigma=2, size=10_000_000)
    # Sampling second sample, same distribution
    sample2 = (np.random.uniform(0, 1, 10_000_000)<0.05)*np.random.lognormal(mean=2.7, sigma=2, size=10_000_000)
    # Performing test
    res = mannwhitneyu(sample1, sample2)
    return(res)
        
# Running simulations in parallel to get results faster
results = Parallel(n_jobs=15)(delayed(process)(i) for i in range(100))
    
### Visualising results
# extracting p values from simulations
p_vals = [el.pvalue for el in results]
# ploting p-values
pd.Series(p_vals).hist()
```

And this is the p-value distribution I am getting:
[image]

So as you can see:

1. I am getting wrong type I error rate (0% type I errors!).
2. The distribution is very far from expected uniform distribution.

The weirdest thing in my opinion is, that exactly same code but with smaller samples (for 1,000 obs or 100,000 in each sample) causes no issue (uniform distribution of p-value). Therefore, I am thinking that due to large numbers involved in calculations, there can be some numerical errors happening that make test statistic much lower than it should be. Also, since issue appears only in zero-inflated distribution (no issue for normal distribution), I believe the issue can be related to large number of zeros in both samples and therefore, large number of tied pairs.

Any ideas, suggestions?

Comment: Hi! To improve your question, you could (should?) mention in plain English what your code is doing, as people able to answer your question do not necessarily know Python (even though I find your code pretty straightforward, I wonder if it's the case for everyone).

Comment: Incidentally, have you checked if the problem remains with a larger number of simulations? (100 seems a bit low to me - I understand it's computationally intensive to multiply this number by 10 or 100, but it may be worth checking if it explains the issue, at least in part).

Comment: I can't reproduce this in R, I get a perfectly uniform distribution.

Comment: Using the same code in Python but with smaller sample sizes (e.g. 100_000 instead of 10_000_000), the distribution under the null behaves much more nicely. As @GeorgeSavva mentions that the issue does not appear in R, I suspect this may be a bug coming either from scipy or from numpy (though it would surprise me if the issue was with numpy). I'd suggest to ask the question on https://stackoverflow.com (using the scipy and numpy tags), or report it here https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues

Comment: @J-J-J thanks, I have added more comments. Regarding number of simulations: yep, it takes time and 100 is quite low. However, I received this result multiple times trying different test parameters, format of input arrays etc., so it is definitly repeatable, and the distribution is very far from unifrom (there not even a single value below 0.35 in 100 trials).

Comment: Your "results" screenshot shows that you are list comprehending over `results2`, rather than `results`, but that is probably a minor detail.

Comment: Might this be due to the parallel processing involved? That can pull a number on pRNGs, they may share state between threads, see also [here](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/parallel_random_state.html) for your specific library. You should make sure that every draw is indeed independent in all of the separate processes.

Comment: With so many zeros you get a lot of equal ranks and it is not so easy to determine the null distribution of the Mann-Whitney U test. Possibly the python function makes a mistake with this like applying a normal distribution approximation.

Comment: Correction to my previous answer. A simulation shows that the approximation formula with ties is not the problem.

Comment: @Pbulls I adapted the code OP posted to get rid of the parallel processing (replaced it with a vanilla for loop), the issue remains. So I'd bet on a bug with scipy, probably more likely to get an answer on stackoverflow or on the scipy issue tracker mentioned earlier. The source code is here if someone feels like getting their hands dirty: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/stats/_mannwhitneyu.py#L251-L519

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an integer overflow in `scipy` (which makes this a programming question, but I digress).

First and foremost, taking R's `wilcox.test` as the ground truth it's clear that the results don't agree. I took the first 100 seeds in `numpy.random` and transferred the generated samples to R, the test statistic is sufficiently similar but the `scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu` *P*-value is consistently inflated:

[image: comparison of statistics]

After digging a bit through the source code the reason for this is due to the following sum in $\sigma_{tie}$ (`scipy` cites [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Normal_approximation_and_tie_correction) for their formulae):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^Kt_k^3-t_k
$$

Let's first create a single sample for reproducibility:

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
N = 10_000_000

x = (np.random.uniform(0, 1, N)<0.05)*np.random.lognormal(mean=2.7, sigma=2, size=N)
y = (np.random.uniform(0, 1, N)<0.05)*np.random.lognormal(mean=2.7, sigma=2, size=N)
```

I'll use the same in R, copying that is left as an exercise (I recommend you don't write the ~9.5 million zeroes). The necessary statistics in `wilcox.test` are calculated like so, ignoring redundant arguments & sanity checks:

```r
r <- rank(c(x, y))
n.x <- as.double(length(x))
n.y <- as.double(length(y))
STATISTIC <- sum(r[seq_along(x)]) - n.x * (n.x + 1) / 2
#> 50004508734553

NTIES <- table(r)

## Actually part of a bigger formula, but this is the critical value
tie_term <- sum(NTIES^3 - NTIES)
#> 6857512065606319341648     (6.8e21)
```

Ignoring a lot of input validation & optional arguments, the rank sum test in `scipy` then goes:

```py
from scipy.stats import rankdata

xy = np.concatenate((x, y), axis=-1)
n1, n2 = x.shape[-1], y.shape[-1]

ranks = rankdata(xy, axis=-1)          ## method 2, step 1
R1 = ranks[..., :n1].sum(axis=-1)      ## method 2, step 2
U1 = R1 - n1*(n1+1)/2                  ## method 2, step 3
#> 50004508734571.5
```

So far so good! Doesn't match perfectly, but the relative error is well below machine epsilon.

```py
_, t = np.unique(ranks, return_counts=True, axis=-1)
tie_term = (t**3 - t).sum(axis=-1)
#> -4676729813634141402    (-4.7e18)
```

*Oops*. Turns out `numpy` and thereby `scipy` uses [`int64`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.int_) here which is platform-dependent but will usually overflow at [$2^{63}-1\approx 9.2\times 10^{18}$](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.int_).

`scipy` simply cannot represent the sum of (a power of) that amount of ties currently, and a fix from the outside may not be possible since this type is set internally -- it's not an unreasonable base assumption that ranks could be represented with integers either.

Comment: In R the type of the variable is silently converted to a floating point in the case of an overflow. That can be criticised. But what does python do? Does it silently convert to 9.2x10^18 without error warnings?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus R starts with floats here by default, you would still get an overflow if these were (32-bit for R) integers but that's an error or at least a warning + cast to `NA`. In Python it simply silently overflows, as evidenced by its result being equal to $2^{63}- (6.8\times 10^{21}\mod 2^{63})$. e: Actually, you might be right that R auto-converts exponentiation of an integer to a float (overflow or not)

Comment: I didn't check what R is doing in the wilcoxon function (which doesn't explicitly define the variables as floats, not?) and I just checked `as.integer(9500000)^3` which returns a floating point. This silently switching of types by R is sometimes criticised, but ignoring an overflow error is even worse behaviour.

Comment: Interestingly when I use a simple expression `x = as.integer(9500000); typeof(x+1)` then R already turns it into a floating point. Instead, I have to do explicitly `x = as.integer(9500000);p = as.integer(1);typeof(x+p)`. But in the case of a power it still switches to floating point as output, even when the output would be a valid integer.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I meant that you cannot have integer input that follows OP's example -- but it's the return of `table` that actually matters, which is (32-bit) `int`. R exponentiation auto-casts that to double which avoids this specific overflow. R would overflow first if you actually have $2^{32}$ ties anywhere, Python could handle $2^{63}$ but still can't cube that. I can't test because running `table` on that many values requires >128Gb RAM. Still, it should be clear that while R trades a bit of precision the end result is much closer to correct and doesn't pass errors silently.

Comment: I see now how the R function casts it in floats to start with. But even when the function wouldn't do that, the power operator in R, which is c++ under the hood, automatically recasts the integer input as floating point.

Comment: Here is a way to hack R to force it to make use of integers when computing a power `Rcpp::cppFunction('int intpow(int x, int p) { return pow(x,p);}'); intpow(as.integer(9500000),as.integer(3))` and it will return NA in the case of an overflow error. The c++ function `pow(x,p)` actually still works, and the NA comes from defining the function as int.

Comment: +1, nice catch. Trying it with the development version of scipy (1.13.0rc1), the issue seems to be fixed, but I didn't test it extensively. Here's how they changed the code internally: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/e8fdbfe477205a3371b15a987cdec59d48e100cb . Hopefully, it should be deployed in a near future. For those wanting to test it in the meantime (@PtrZlnk ?), you can use `pip install scipy==1.13.0rc1` to install the dev version.

Comment: @J-J-J that's excellent, seems like their fix was (will be) to use `dtype=float` for the counts table.

Answer (score 2):

At least there is no problem with the approximation formula (I believe this is applied by python, otherwise it should have already problems for small values as well).

A code below in R demonstrates this. The code is computing the statistic slightly indirectly because my computer can't sample and order 10 millions of samples so well.

[image: example with case from R]

```
sim = function() {
  n = 10000000
  m = 2*n
  
  ### compute/simulate ranks
  ### this is not done by sampling and ordering a random variable
  ### instead we sample the ranks directly 
  k1 = rbinom(1,n,0.95)  ### the number of zero's for both samples is binomial distributed
  k2 = rbinom(1,n,0.95)
  ties = k1+k2
  ranks = (ties+1):(2*n) ### the remaining ranks 
  r1 = sample(ranks,n-k1)   ### which will be randomly distributed among samples 1 and 2
  
  ### compute the statistic based on the ranks of sample 1
  R1 = k1*(ties+1)/2 + sum(r1)
  U = R1 - n*(n+1)/2
  
  ### compare with normal distribution approximation
  sig = sqrt(n^2/12*(m+1-(ties^3-ties)/m/(m-1) ))
  mu = n^2/2 
  z = (U-mu)/sig
  p = pnorm(z)
  
  return(p)
}

### repeat simulations and plot histogram
set.seed(1)
p = replicate(10^3,sim())
hist(p)
```